# Getting Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apach.logging.log4j.Logger while deploying ear module in WebLogic 12C

Tags: web, ejb, weblogic, classnotfoundexception, ear

I'm getting Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apach.logging.log4j.Logger while deploying ear module in WebLogic 12C. Ear module contains EJB & Web Modules.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What is the issue? If you have a problem or error then add details describing it. The stacktrace is required to analyze the cause of error. Look up the server log for errors then add it to the question. Did you use Struts2 to your project?

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved after i added org.apach.logging.log4j log4j-api & log4j-core maven dependencies in ear, ejb & web pom.xmls.

I've extracted ear file and verified log4j jars classpath in Mainfest.mf file.